# Difference between addFilter and addListener

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I want to know what is the difference between addFilter and addListener methods in Display class conceptually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display`, if so:

In the normal case `addFilter` and `addListener` will both be notified of the same events, however `addFilter` will be called earlier.

Where they are different is that the listener added with `addFilter` can cancel the event from being dispatched to the listeners added with `addListener`, it does this by setting the `event.type` to `SWT.None`:

From the [javadocs](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#addFilter(int,%20org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener)) of `addFilter`:

> Setting the type of an event to SWT.None from within the handleEvent()
>   method can be used to change the event type and stop subsequent Java
>   listeners from running. Because event filters run before other
>   listeners, event filters can both block other listeners and set
>   arbitrary fields within an event. For this reason, event filters are
>   both powerful and dangerous. They should generally be avoided for
>   performance, debugging and code maintenance reasons.

Note the last part about event filters **"[...] both powerful and dangerous. They should generally be avoided [...]"**